# Dynamic pivot multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with results like this:

```
EMP_ID  | Boss_ID | Boss_Name | Specialty

  1001     001      John             sql
  1001     001      John             c#
  1002     002      James            c++
  1002     003      Sarah            sql
  1002     003      Sarah            python
  1003     004      Jesse            networking
```

Employees can have multiple bosses which can have multiple specialties.

I need to dynamically pivot the data so that I have one line per employee. I need to display the employee, all the bosses they have and just their line 1 specialty.

I am able to use dynamic pivot and display the multiple bosses part but I am unsure of how to display their specialty next to their name.

Here is what I have:

```
   DECLARE @cols        AS NVARCHAR(max)
          ,@query       AS NVARCHAR(max)

   select t.EMP_ID 
         ,t.Boss_Name
         ,t.Boss_ID
         ,t.Specialty
         ,'BOSS' + '_' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.EMP_ID ORDER BY t.BOSS_ID asc) AS VARCHAR) AS b_rn
         ,'SPEC' + '_' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Specialty ORDER BY t.BOSS_ID asc) AS VARCHAR) AS spec_rn
   INTO #work 
   from #testing t

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
                  (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + w.b_rn  
                   FROM #work w
                   ORDER BY '],[' + w.b_rn
                   FOR XML PATH('') 
                  ), 1, 2, ''
                ) + ']'

PRINT @cols

SET @query = N' SELECT EMP_ID,' + @cols + N' 
            INTO ##work_results FROM 
                 (
                  SELECT EMP_ID
                        ,Boss_Name
                        ,b_rn 

                  FROM #work
                  ) AS sourcetable 
PIVOT
(
 max(Boss_Name) for b_rn IN ('+ @cols + N') 
 ) AS pivot_table'


execute(@query)

select * from ##work_results
```

This gives me:

```
EMP_ID  |   BOSS_1  |   BOSS_2  |   BOSS_3
1001        John       John          NULL
1002        James      Sarah         Sarah
1003        Jesse      NULL          NULL
```

What I am really looking for is results like this:

```
  EMP_ID | Boss_1 | Specialty_1 | Boss_2 | Specialty_1   

  1001     John     sql 
  1002     James    c++           Sarah      sql
  1003     Jesse    networking
```

I have looked at other posts but they aren't quite what I am looking for.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the limitations of PIVOT. It can't pivot multiple columns. I prefer to use a dynamic cross tab even with a single column. For me the syntax is less obtuse and it even enjoys a slight performance benefit. Here is a great article explaining how this works. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: I will read that article. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Maybe you could join `pivot_table` back to `#testing` to get the specialties for each boss.   You would have to join once for each boss column though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might go this way:

The trick is, to concatenate your values. Therefore only one column, no problem with pivot...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(EMP_ID INT,Boss_ID INT,Boss_Name VARCHAR(100),Specialty VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1001,001,'John','sql')
,(1001,001,'John','c#')
,(1002,002,'James','c++')
,(1002,003,'Sarah','sql')
,(1002,003,'Sarah','python')
,(1003,004,'Jesse','networking');

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.EMP_ID
          --If you need your Bosses in the given order you must add a sort crit to your original table!
          ,'Column_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.EMP_ID ORDER BY tbl.EMP_ID) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnName
          ,tbl.Boss_Name + ' (' +  tbl.Specialty + ')' AS Concatenated
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS ToBePivoted
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Concatenated) FOR ColumnName IN(Column_1,Column_2,Column_3 /*add maximum here*/)
) As p
```

The result

```
1001    John (sql)          John (c#)     NULL
1002    James (c++)         Sarah (sql)   Sarah (python)
1003    Jesse (networking)  NULL          NULL
```

If you need the values separated another trick is, to concatenate all needed columns in XML-format (but not XML-Type!).

As the concatenation is XML-Format it is quite easy to extract the elements just via their index.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(EMP_ID INT,Boss_ID INT,Boss_Name VARCHAR(100),Specialty VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1001,001,'John','sql')
,(1001,001,'John','c#')
,(1002,002,'James','c++')
,(1002,003,'Sarah','sql')
,(1002,003,'Sarah','python')
,(1003,004,'Jesse','networking');

SELECT p.EMP_ID

      ,CAST(Column_1 AS XML).value('x[1]','int') AS BossID_1 
      ,CAST(Column_1 AS XML).value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS BossName_1 
      ,CAST(Column_1 AS XML).value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS specialty_1 

      ,CAST(Column_2 AS XML).value('x[1]','int') AS BossID_2 
      ,CAST(Column_2 AS XML).value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS BossName_2
      ,CAST(Column_2 AS XML).value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS specialty_2 

      ,CAST(Column_3 AS XML).value('x[1]','int') AS BossID_3 
      ,CAST(Column_3 AS XML).value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS BossName_3 
      ,CAST(Column_3 AS XML).value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS specialty_3 
      /*Add a maximum here*/
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.EMP_ID
          --If you need your Bosses in the given order you must add a sort crit to your original table!
          ,'Column_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.EMP_ID ORDER BY tbl.EMP_ID) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnName
          ,'<x>' + CAST(tbl.Boss_ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '</x><x>' +  tbl.Boss_Name + '</x><x>' +  tbl.Specialty + '</x>' AS ValuesAsXML
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS ToBePivoted
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ValuesAsXML) FOR ColumnName IN(Column_1,Column_2,Column_3 /*add maximum here*/)
) As p
```

The result

```
1001    1   John    sql         1       John    c#      NULL    NULL    NULL
1002    2   James   c++         3       Sarah   sql     3       Sarah   python
1003    4   Jesse   networking  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: ha I actually tried the concatenate method at first but the end user wants the specialty in its own column. As for your second method, that works, but that's if I know the number of columns there will be. The number of bosses is variable so I wouldn't be able to list out the columns here. (apologies if I'm missing something) Thanks!

Comment: @jw133, All right, the end user is the king ;-) And what about the XML-trick?

Comment: oops that was meant to be more of a question. For the XML trick, i'm a little confused in how to set it up dynamically. The example you posted works great, but only if I know how many columns (in this case 3).

Comment: @jw133, do you know a maximum number? Will there be hundreds of Bossess and Specialities? If not, you might just define the expected maximum (and maybe some more :-)   ) With dynamic SQL you also won't know, how many columns are coming back. One benefit here is, that you might create an inline UDF.

Comment: @jw133, hi, I just saw you are still around... Could you solve your problem?